# Excel data merge

Tags: excel

I have two tables in excel from two data sources. I would like to merge the tables and still be able to refresh and update them.

```
  First table columns:
  Request Type, Customer, Status
  Second table columns:
  Request Type, Customer, Status
```

As you can see, this is a simple merge, but copying data from one table to another will not allow me to update both tables.

Thank you all in advance.
T

Comment: what are the data sources?

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with Power Query, a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013 and built into Excel 2016 as Get & Transform.

Load the first table as a connection only. Load the next table, then append the query for the first table. The resulting table can be refreshed when the underlying data changes.

This can all be done by clicking a few buttons in the Power Query Editor. No formulas and no VBA.